# Removing VHD's from Azure Resource Manager after removing VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

It was brought to my attention that, if you create a new VM and then delete it (and its associated resources), you do *not* in fact delete the corresponding VHD file -- that file is left in blob storage, blocking the provisioning of a new machine with the same hostname, and also costing real money for wasted and unused storage. I wish to delete the VHD's along with the VM's.

Where can I find a good write-up of the *current* wisdom on how to deal with this? All I can find is references from before 2013 which evidently target the "classic" version.

I have written up the following code to try to remedy this situation. I have two use cases, first of all I have to get rid of all the accumulated junk, and after that I "just" need to make sure to clean up after each future machine when it is deleted.

```
write-output("Removing orphaned disks for hostname ""$hostname"" ...")
$storageContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Where-Object{$_.StorageAccountName -match $azureStorage}).Context
$storageBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container "vhds"
$vhdList = $storageBlob | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "$hostname"}
foreach($disk in $vhdList) {
    $diskname = $disk.Name
    write-output("Removing VHD ""$diskname"" ...")
    Remove-AzureDisk -Diskname "$diskname" -DeleteVHD
    write-output("Removed VHD ""$diskname"" ... [OK]")
}
write-output("Removed orphaned disks ... [OK]")
```

Now, when I run that, I get nice listings of the VHD files I expect to see (and also some corresponding "*.status" files). However, the `Remove-AzureDisk` command yields the error `Remove-AzureDisk : ResourceNotFound: The disk with the specified name does not exist` so it's not really working.

You'll notice that I switch from the new "ARM" commands to the "classic" version half-way through -- this is likely part of my problem, but I've had no luck in coming up with better commands.

**Update:**

This seems to do the trick:

```
# Verify that the OS VHD does not already exist
write-output("Checking for blocking VHD's ...")
$storageContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Where-Object{$_.StorageAccountName -match $azureStorage}).Context
$storageBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container "vhds"
$vhdList = $storageBlob | Where-Object{$_.Name -match "$hostname"}
if ($vhdList) {
    write-output("There is an existing VHD blocking host ""$hostname"" in storage container ""$($storageContext.BlobEndPoint)vhds""):")
    foreach($vhdName in $vhdList.Name) {
        write-output("- $vhdName")
    }
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
    $answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("There is an existing VHD blocking host ""$hostname"" in storage container ""$($storageContext.BlobEndPoint)vhds"").`nDo you wish to remove the existing VHD file?" , "Create New VM" , $MB_YESNO)
    if ($answer -eq "YES" ) {
        # Remove VHD files
        foreach($diskName in $vhdList.Name) {
            write-output("- Removing VHD ""$diskName""")
            Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $diskName -Container "vhds" -Context $storageContext
        }
        write-output("Checked for blocking VHD's ... [OK]")
    } else {
        exit(331)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you delete the VM? what command do you use?

Comment: For testing, I remove the VM through the web interface. As far as I (since recently) understand, this has the nasty effect of leaving the VHD in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general wisdom of Azure Resource Management is that you stop thinking about resources in atomic units, like VMs, storage, networks, and instead you start thinking of them as a group of resources. A resource group, as it were ;)

The theory is that you create a template that creates an entire deployment in a single go, either via Rest, Powershell, or template file.

then instead of deleting the VM and recreating it, you delete the entire Resource Group, and run the deployment again and you'll be back to exactly where you were.

It does make the whole thing much more manageable, and allows for much more complex builds.

Using that model, if you delete the entire resource group, then all of the underlying resources, blobs, storage accounts, networks will be deleted.

So, on to your problem.

Azure doesn't create disks in the same way that classic manager did. Basically you point the machine to a blob vhd and that's it. So the problem with your command is that there isn't any disk to delete.

So the command you would want

```
Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $diskname -Container vhds -Context $context
```

Comment: I've thought about doing just that (one dedicated resource group per VM), but the setup I'm given _currently_ revolves around many VM's in a single group. It is, however, very likely I can challenge that, especially given such good motivation.

Comment: do you specifically need to add and remove VMs independently of each other? Are there any groupings you can use around them. The bigger groups you can break them into - that you can subsequently treat as a single unit - the easier management will be.

Comment: Yes, individually; these are test machines running (independent) test suites. Would there be a problem in having 50-100 resource groups at any one time, plus _quite a bit_ of turnover?

Comment: I deleted the resource group. The list of VHDs is unaffected. :-( I don't think that approach is going to work. There _must_ be some form of "formal correct approach" that's (obviously) non-obvious.

Comment: @klaymendk there is a better way, you could use vm scale sets, if you post a new question outlining you're problem I'll write a proper answer when I'm back in front of a keyboard!

Comment: Thank you, that's very nice of you. But are scale sets relevant? I mean, this is not "one work load" that needs to scale, these are completely separate boxes doing separate tasks (via MS Test Manager).

Comment: @klaymendk it's not strictly how they're intended to be used, and I'll need to check a couple of things (when I'm not on mobile!) But I think with a little persuasion they could do just what you're looking for (of course I could well be completely wrong, and you might just need to script the whole thing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102689/discussion-between-michael-b-and-klaymendk).

Answer (score 0):

Check server clock and client clock

The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes by the time it reaches the service. This guards against certain security attacks, including replay attacks. When this check fails, the server returns response code 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: I'm a little confused at how this relates to the question?

Comment: My assumption is as he can't find the resources when he tired to delete using Remove-AzureDisk, maybe because the clock, so just double check for that part.

Comment: That's because it was an ARM machine and they don't have disks ;)